# Error while processing route: index Cannot read property 'fixturesForType' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixturesForType' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

I have just started with ember.js. While working with fixtures and displaying the data on my page I am getting `undefined Typeerror`.

My code looks like 
Category.js

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({

    title:DS.attr('string')

});

App.Category.reopenClass({

FIXTURES: [

{id: 1, title: "Produce"},

{id: 2, title: "Baking"},

{id: 3, title: "Household"},

{id: 4, title: "New category"}

]
});
```

Model.js

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model:function(){

        return this.store.find('category');

    }
});
```

template

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">All</li>
    {{#each}}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{title}}</li>    
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an old Ember/tutorial version. Your `each` block should look like this:

```
{{#each item in model}}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{item.title}}</li>    
{{/each}}
```

See: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sicuriwoza/1/edit?html,output